# How to create an object for a model from the console similar to how Django made the createsuperuser command

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, command-line

I'm trying to create an object from the console but not sure how to set that up.
This is my modelManager:

```
class MajorManager(models.Manager):

def __str__(self):
    return self.name 

def createMajor(self, name):
    try:
        name = name.lower()
        major = self.create(name=name)    
    except IntegrityError:
        print("This major has already been created")
```

And here is the model:

```
class Majors(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
objects = MajorManager()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can go this route using Django's API - [checkout the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api)

First create a shell:

`python manage.py shell`

Then you can import your models and do basic `CRUD` on them.

```
>>> from polls.models import Choice, Question  # Import the model classes we just wrote.

# No questions are in the system yet.
>>> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>

# Create a new Question.
# Support for time zones is enabled in the default settings file, so
# Django expects a datetime with tzinfo for pub_date. Use timezone.now()
# instead of datetime.datetime.now() and it will do the right thing.
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())

# Save the object into the database. You have to call save() explicitly.
>>> q.save()
```

Or, alternatively you can try the `dbshell` route, here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#dbshell).

> This command assumes the programs are on your PATH so that a simple
> call to the program name (psql, mysql, sqlite3, sqlplus) will find the
> program in the right place. There’s no way to specify the location of
> the program manually.

You can't use the Django's ORM though, it's pure SQL, so it would be instructions like:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  Id Int,
  Name Varchar
);
```